How to change coordinates of a differential operator?
Say for example, I start with $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and want to change x to the spherical coordinate
$$x = \rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$
I know this isn't correct, by my brain immediately goes $\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)}$. What would instead be the process for this example and/or what is the general process for changing variables for differential operators?

I'm assuming the following will at some point be referenced: the function that will be differentiated being $f(x,y,z)$, and in spherical coordinates along only x becomes $g\big(x(\theta,\phi,\rho),y,z\big)$. Correct?

Almost. Express $f$ in new coordinates and use chain rule.

It would go from $$f(x,y,z) \rightarrow f(x(\theta,\phi,\rho),y,z)$$ and it's been a while since I've done chain rule, but I think that would be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d\rho} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$$. Then I guess I can pull out the function we're differentiating and re-arrange and then we have $$\frac{1}{\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} = \frac{d}{dx}$$. Look about right?

@KurtG. Wait I think the way it's done similar to how it was done in this answer. I am not familiar with how the chain rule on just $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is performed otherwise. If that's the case, it would be $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial x}$$ I know what $\rho$ is but I'm afraid I don't know the equations for $\theta$ and $\phi$

@KurtG.A quick google search and it looks like $$\theta = \arctan\frac{y}{x}$$ (so the eqn for $\theta$ didn't change from polar coordinates) and $$\phi = \arccos\Big(\frac{z}{\rho}\Big)$$. I might be able to work out the answer then if what I have above is correct for the chain rule applied to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$

There is no chain rule on "just" $\frac{\partial}{\partial x},.$ Get into rabbit hole and patiently work it out rather than googling and what not.

@KurtG. Well to start, the only way I know how to use chain rule is by taking the derivatives of the function. So, by taking the derivatives: $$\frac{df}{d\rho} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d\rho} = \sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$ $$\frac{d\rho}{d\phi} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{d\phi} = \rho\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$ $$\frac{df}{d\theta} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{d\theta} = -\rho\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$. I don't believe this is what you meant by using chain rule

It is not. The trouble started when you wrote $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho},.$ The function $f$ is either a function of $(x,y,z)$ or of $(\rho,\phi,\theta)$ but not both. Write
$$
g(\rho,\phi,\theta)=f(x,y,z)
$$
where $x,y,z$ are now functions of $\rho,\phi,\theta,.$ Then apply the multivariate chain rule. Hint: you should get

$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial \rho} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \rho} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \rho} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \rho}
$$
and so on. When you drop $f$ and $g$ from these equations you have your transformation rules.

@KurtG. From my James Stewart 8th edition calculus textbook, in the 1 section it focuses on transformation of variables (for multivariate functions), I have seen $$T(u,v) = (x,y)$$ as in the coordinate (x,y), and from there $$x = g(u,v) \ \ \ \ \ y = g(u,v)$$ or it can also be written $$x = x(u,v) \ \ \ \ \ y = y(u,v)$$, though I think it makes sense if we equate the two functions $T(u,v) = f(x,y)$, the transform variables  have to be functions of the Cartesian variables or vice versa, otherwise we wouldn't be able to equate them. Thank you for helping to make that much clear to me!

Its the other way around. The differential is trivially
$$d(f(x))= d(f(\rho \cos \phi \sin \theta)) = f'(\rho \cos \phi \sin \theta)))(d\rho \cos \phi \sin \theta - d\phi \sin \phi \sin \theta + d\theta \cos \phi \cos \theta)$$ and getting expressions of derivatives one has to solve for the inverses for functions of all three variables $x,y,z$wrt. to the inverses of $$\left( \frac{1}{d\rho},\frac{1}{d\phi},\frac{1}{d\theta}\right)$$.
So linear algebra of solving systems of equations is inevitable.

I'm afraid I do not know how to use linear algebra

I was suggested (and I've seen it be suggested in a couple other places I've searched a similar type of problem) that we leverage chain rule. I'm not too keen on the specifics as I'm not the best at chain rule, but perhaps that's an alternative
